# recognize observation which are in the certain quantile: data science pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

i have a big df, this is a example to ilustrate my issue. I want to know from this dataframe whichs id are in the first percent in terms of jobs. I want to identify (i am thinking with a dummy) the one percent which has more jobs from the distribution

for example

```
id  year  rap  cohort    jobs  year_of_life  rap_new
1   2009    0     NaN      10      NaN       0  
2   2012    0     2012     12      0         0   
3   2013    0     2012     12      1         1
4   2014    0     2012     13      2         1
5   2015    1     2012     15      3         1
6   2016    0     2012     17      4         0
7   2017    0     2012     19      5         0
8   2009    0     2009     15      0         1
9   2010    0     2009     2       1         1
10  2011    0     2009     3       2         1
11  2012    1     2009     3       3         0
12  2013    0     2009     15      4         0
13  2014    0     2009     12      5         0
14  2015    0     2009     13      6         0
15  2016    0     2009     13      7         0
16  2011    0     2009     3       2         1
17  2012    1     2009     3       3         0
18  2013    0     2009     18      4         0
19  2014    0     2009     12      5         0
20  2015    0     2009     13      6         0
.....
100 2009    0     2007     5       6         1
```

transform to something like this maybe, in this dataframe as we have 100 ids one percent from 100 is one, and then look for the biggest id in jobs. My really df varies the number of observation that's why im looking for some standar code which will alwayas apply no matter what is the number of observation

```
id  year  rap  cohort    jobs  year_of_life  rap_new  new_var
1   2009    0     NaN      10      NaN       0          0
2   2012    0     2012     12      0         0          0
3   2013    0     2012     12      1         1          0
4   2014    0     2012     13      2         1          0
5   2015    1     2012     15      3         1          0
6   2016    0     2012     17      4         0          0
7   2017    0     2012     18      5         0          0
8   2009    0     2009     15      0         1          0
9   2010    0     2009     2       1         1          0
10  2011    0     2009     3       2         1          0
11  2012    1     2009     3       3         0          0
12  2013    0     2009     15      4         0          0
13  2014    0     2009     12      5         0          0
14  2015    0     2009     13      6         0          0
15  2016    0     2009     13      7         0          0
16  2011    0     2009     3       2         1          0
17  2012    1     2009     3       3         0          0
18  2013    0     2009     19      4         0          1
19  2014    0     2009     12      5         0          0
20  2015    0     2009     13      6         0          0
.....
100 2009    0     2007     5       6         1          0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pd.Series.quantile` to identify the cut-off

**Setup**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed([3, 1415])
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    id=range(1, 201),
    jobs=np.random.randint(100, 10000, size=200)
))
```

---

**Solution**

```
df[df.jobs >= df.jobs.quantile(.99)]

      id  jobs
23    24  9768
182  183  9965
```

Comment: thank you very much! may i ask you something new? if i want to perform the same idea but by a certain characteristic (i didnt post it that specific characteristic). but imagine i want too know the first percent which higgher jobs by years_of_life

Comment: IIUC, you need to use `groupby`.  Put it in another question so you have an opportunity to make it very clear what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

`pandas` comes with a `rank` method, to either get the `rank` or `percentile`. You could probably work with:

```
In [8]: df['percentile'] = df.jobs.rank(pct=True)

In [9]: df
Out[9]:
    id  year  rap  cohort  jobs  year_of_life  rap_new  percentile
0    1  2009    0     NaN    10           NaN        0       0.300
1    2  2012    0  2012.0    12           0.0        0       0.425
2    3  2013    0  2012.0    12           1.0        1       0.425
3    4  2014    0  2012.0    13           2.0        1       0.625
4    5  2015    1  2012.0    15           3.0        1       0.800
5    6  2016    0  2012.0    17           4.0        0       0.900
6    7  2017    0  2012.0    19           5.0        0       1.000
7    8  2009    0  2009.0    15           0.0        1       0.800
8    9  2010    0  2009.0     2           1.0        1       0.050
9   10  2011    0  2009.0     3           2.0        1       0.175
10  11  2012    1  2009.0     3           3.0        0       0.175
11  12  2013    0  2009.0    15           4.0        0       0.800
12  13  2014    0  2009.0    12           5.0        0       0.425
13  14  2015    0  2009.0    13           6.0        0       0.625
14  15  2016    0  2009.0    13           7.0        0       0.625
15  16  2011    0  2009.0     3           2.0        1       0.175
16  17  2012    1  2009.0     3           3.0        0       0.175
17  18  2013    0  2009.0    18           4.0        0       0.950
18  19  2014    0  2009.0    12           5.0        0       0.425
19  20  2015    0  2009.0    13           6.0        0       0.625
```

So to filter for rows in the top 1%:

```
In [10]: df[df.percentile > 0.99]
Out[10]:
   id  year  rap  cohort  jobs  year_of_life  rap_new  percentile
6   7  2017    0  2012.0    19           5.0        0         1.0
```

Or top 50%:

```
In [12]: df[df.percentile > 0.50]
Out[12]:
    id  year  rap  cohort  jobs  year_of_life  rap_new  percentile
3    4  2014    0  2012.0    13           2.0        1       0.625
4    5  2015    1  2012.0    15           3.0        1       0.800
5    6  2016    0  2012.0    17           4.0        0       0.900
6    7  2017    0  2012.0    19           5.0        0       1.000
7    8  2009    0  2009.0    15           0.0        1       0.800
11  12  2013    0  2009.0    15           4.0        0       0.800
13  14  2015    0  2009.0    13           6.0        0       0.625
14  15  2016    0  2009.0    13           7.0        0       0.625
17  18  2013    0  2009.0    18           4.0        0       0.950
19  20  2015    0  2009.0    13           6.0        0       0.625
```